# Title of PopUp in Contact Support is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, firefox, popups

There seems to be a problem with Firefox 23 when displaying the PopUps in the Contact Support. The title of the PopUp is missing (see Screenshot below, it should display "How to delete your account")

IE 10 and latest Chrome displays the title correctly.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [Contact Us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)
2. Select Option "I need to delete my user profile"
3. PopUp opens -> Title is missing

The title is also missing when choosing another option.

The title of PopUps for flagging or closing a post are displayed in FireFox.

[image: Title missing in FireFox 23]

When opening the PopUp in FireFox the console logs an CSS-Error `[22:34:41.911] Error in parsing value for 'left'.  Declaration dropped.` *I dont´t know if its related to the problem*.

Comment: You're leaving? :0

Comment: @Undo No not really. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build, working in all browsers.

Comment: No dirty little secrets this time on what caused this? :-(

Comment: When does the next build roll out? Current version of meta is 2013.8.6.1318. I´ll wait some time to check again and accept your answer.

Comment: Just noticed that the "Get more details"-Button also does not work. Is it related to the problem?

Comment: @Jehof yes same bug, also fixed in the next build, sometime this morning.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd nothing interesting here, Firefox just handles innerText on `<script type="text/plain">` here differently.  Next deploy doesn't use those and is much more concise, data attributes do just fine for the links and titles.

Comment: @Nick thanks, that's just enough for me. :-)